# Need help exorcising weird gremlin from PHP fwrite

Tags: php, fwrite

In the following code, $output is a string of lines each 804 characters long including a new line character at the end of each line. At position 454 in each line there is a "Y". It's just a plain old "Y", as in "Yes".

```
$fh = fopen($filename_with_path,"w");
fwrite($fh,$output);
fclose($fh);
```

For some reason, when viewing the file that gets created, the entire output seems to be intact, but position 454 is a blank and the "Y" is no where to be found.

I can have a die($output) either before or after the above code, and the output contains the "Y". I had the script email me the contents of $output, and it contained the "Y". But when I look at the file that is created (and I've confirmed it's being created anew each time I run the script), instead of a "Y" there is a blank space. (I've looked at the file on the filesystem using "cat" and also as a web download opened in Notepad, and the "Y" just isn't there.

When the created file has two lines in it, it is 1608 bytes long, which makes sense since each line has 804. So this really makes it look like the one Y is getting swapped with a blank. There are other Y's in the output that appear fine in the file.

I am totally baffled by this. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: So you say the char is there, you can see it in a dump, in an email, but not on the file you create. What kind of file are you creating? If it were a normal txt file, would it show? Does the "Y" and the surrounding chars have any special meaning in the file type you're creating?

Comment: For your exorcising needs: Take the hard disk out of the computer and place it into a magnetic resonance tomographic device in a hospital near you and switch it on.

Comment: What is the source of the content? You sure it's in a character encoding that doesn't have artifacts? By that I mean the Y may be an interpretation of an unfamiliar encoding, yet interpreted as a blank space depending on what's trying to read it

Comment: Use [`var_dump`](http://php.net/var_dump) instead of (before) `die`. **Edit:** Also please try `"wb"` [fopen mode](http://php.net/fopen).

Comment: The script is reading values out of a database and creating a left-justified fixed-column-length text file. The fields are VARCHAR in the (MySQL) db. I will try to wb and var_dump and report back.

Answer (score 0):

Uggh. I figured it out. There is always a reason for weirdness, always. Just got to figure it out.

In this case, before the file was being copied to a web accessible directory it was being created in the tmp directory. The web-directory file had a unique filename each time the script ran, but the tmp directory filename didn't.

Since I ran the script manually, the file in the tmp directory was owned by me. Then when I ran the script from the web (the one that creates the file), it didn't have permissions to overwrite the file, and my lack of error checking in the code burned me. The same (old) file was getting copied to the web directory each time, and since that file had a new timestamp, I figured it was new content.

Some lessons (re)learned: have proper error checking always! And know that when something is weird, it is you, not the server, nor the programming language, nor gremlims!!

Thanks StackOverflow community!